# Relationship between mean of square and mean of cube to square and cube

Tags: means

Say I have a quantity I am measuring in time $u=\bar{u}+u'$, where $\bar{u}$ is the mean value and $u'$ is the fluctuating value. How can I find the relationship between $(\bar{u})^2$, $(\bar{u})^3$ and $\overline{u^2}$, $\overline{u^3}$ in terms of $u'/\bar{u}$?

In general, what is the relationship between the mean of the square/cube vs the square/cube of the mean?

Comment: Are you talking about mean as in a probabilistic mean, or as in the average value over a time interval?